# How to print the result of an if else statement into a specific text box

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a relatively new coder who wants to try out the iOS development language "Swift". The app I am creating is a weather app that will show the degrees in celsius and possibly some advice which is where the if statement comes in. However, I am encountering an issue with my code which I do not know how to solve.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var weatherLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var quote: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let apiKey = "60e0655f404d7bf1"
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.wunderground.com/api/eb56be2ac82d34b5/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Canada/Toronto.json") 
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
        let weather = json["current_observation"]!!["temp_c"]

        weatherLabel.text = "\(weather!!)"
        var quote = weather
        var celsius = 20

        if celsius >= quote {
            print("Its cold outside, bring a jacket!") 
        }else{
            print("Its hot outside, remember to drink water!") //if the weather in celsius is over 20 degrees, say ("Its hot outside, remember to drink water!")
        }
    } catch {
        print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
}
```

Does anyone know how I can set the quote in one specific text label and the degrees in the weatherLabel?

I also have an error saying that I can't convert `AnyObject` to an `int`.

Comment: I made a GET request from the url you are requesting the data, and the json didn't retrieve me an `current_observation` object

Comment: @pableiros There was a lot of signing up, key usage but in the end they had a document on the web that was frequently updated, which makes me think that there is no problem with the data, instead, the problem is coming from the if statement as they sent me an error message saying that I was not allowed to convert AnyObject to an int, is there any way to fix it so that when the temperature is over 25 celsius, the quote tells me to drink more water in one of the two text fields with the second field actually giving the degree in celsius?

Comment: Could you add the json response from the request?

Comment: @pableiros I double checked and turns out it was not working... sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score -1):

Var quote = Int(weather) use this.